# Is there an equivalent of Lightroom's profiles in Capture One?

Tags: lightroom, capture-one

I am trying to decide between investing into Lightroom or Capture One.

Besides `presets` (that are equivalent to Capture one's `styles`) Lightroom also has `profiles` which do not change slider positions and thus can be applied in any point of the workflow. Is there something like that in Capture One?

Answer (score 3):

If you are referring to the Camera Profiles in LR (based on DCP profiles), then it's the [Base Characteristics' ICC Profile](https://support.captureone.com/hc/en-us/articles/360002593678) that you're looking for. Essentially, this is "early" in the adjustment/rendering stack, and allows you to adjust the fundamental color interpretation from the file.

The Color Editor tool is also an ICC profile editor in disguise. You can leverage that tool to tweak the chosen ICC profile and save it out to a  custom profile, allowing you to adjust this fundamental response as you see fit, to [create custom camera profiles](https://support.captureone.com/hc/en-us/articles/360002602258-Saving-a-color-scheme-as-an-ICC-profile).

Comment: Hi, welcome to Photography Stack Exchange. Great first answer! Especially for a low-volume topic such as Capture One.